# How to list all contacts of email without the Oauth api?

Tags: c#, .net, api, gmail, contacts

I'm looking for an example code how to list all contacts of gmail using `C#.NET` and one API.

I need do it fast and no complications as using the Oauth api.  The OAuth api is my last alternative.

Comment: @bryanmac:I tried using the OAuth api, but this returns a lot of erros and I can not use it because it is a winforms application.

Comment: who says you can't use OAuth on winforms?

Comment: @Muad'Dib: I found only it: http://code.google.com/p/orkut-oauth-api-csharp/ 
for asp.net. how to use it for winFoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Context.IO API - there's a call specifically for pulling contacts: http://context.io/docs/2.0/accounts/contacts